# How to Properly Encode User data with Firebase using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, swiftui, encoding

I am trying to utilize FirebaseFirestoreSwift in order to preform the following encoding of user data. When I try to run the app, however, I am greeted with the error message "No such module "FirebaseFirestoreSwift". I went into the source for this and it states that it has been moved to FirebaseFirestore and will no longer accept FirebaseFirestoreSwift imports. I tried to switch it to FirebaseFirestore and no luck. Does anyone have any reccomendations on how to fix this error? Thanks!

Code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift


class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?

    init(){
    
    
    }

    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String) async throws{
        print("Sign in...")
    
    }
    
    func createUser(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) async throws{
        do{
        
            let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            let user = User(id: result.user.uid, fullname: fullname, email: email)
            let encodedUser = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
            try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.id).setData(encodedUser)
        
        
        }catch{
            print("DEBUG: Failed to create user with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    
    }
}
```

Again as said above, I tried differing FirebaseFirestore imports and nothing seemed to work with my code above.

Comment: You don’t need to add a step for encoding, one of the set data methods will take in the user object itself and do everything for you. Just let Xcode prefill. I think it is “setData(from:)”

Comment: Solved this myself by adding the FirebaseFirestore framework under the project settings since it is not in there already for some reason. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: If you have resolved the question by your self that it great. Please update the question and close it if no longer expecting answers

Comment: No need to manually encode / decode data when using Firestore. The Firebase SDK does that for you. See this page in the docs for all the details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping